# link_to generating the wrong url structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3, Ubuntu 10.04 and Ruby 1.8.7.

```
link_to "name", lettings_path(lettings)
```

is producing a link: `/lettings.id` and not `/lettings/id` as I would have expected.

in my `routes.rb` file I have:

```
resources :lettings
```

My model name is `Letting`.

This has me completely stumped, never in 6 years have I come across this - I would really appreciate any ideas you guys might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange. The `lettings` variable you use - is it an instance of `Letting` or an array of lettings?

Btw, do you know that in rails 3 you don't need to use the letting_path helper? Just do it like that:

```
= link_to "name", letting
```

Comment: letting is an instance in a partial which is called using a collection of lettings. Interestingly using the "link_to" you suggested solved the problem.... That is very odd. Thanks for the help :-)